# Use of for with map

Tags: perl

map, according to the definition, takes a list on which we can perform some transformations and then return it as a list. Some may even go and call it as a for loop in disguise.

I recently came across some code which in simple terms was using for and map together. For example:

```
perl -wE'@a=(1..5); say $_ for map { $_+=10 } @a'
11
12
13
14
15
```

My question is, is there an easy to way to remember when to use for and map together. Can someone please explain why is that for needed?

Comment: There's nothing to "remember". If you want to loop over something, you use `for`. If that "something" is the result of `map`, you use them together. There's nothing special going on here, it's just combining two features.

Comment: Note: Don't use `+=` unless you actually mean to modify your original array `@a`.  Instead just use `+`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `for` is used to loop through the list returned by `map` and print out each element.

Your example has the same effect as:

```
@l = map {$_ += 10} @a;
for (@l) {
    say $_;
}
```

If all you want is the list, then you don't need `for`:

```
@l = map {$_ += 10} @a
```

Answer (score 1):

`map` returns a new list, `for` iterates over that list. Your `for map` line basically boils down to:

```
@a=(1..5);
@mapped = map { $_+=10 } @a;
for (@mapped) {
  say $_;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify your example:

```
perl -wE 'map { say $_+=10 } (1..5)'
```

As you see, map can be used to execute code of each item. I use map when I have to transform an array into another one. Your example is (IMO) more readable with a for loop:

```
perl -wE 'say $_+=10 for(1..5)'
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it would be helpful to split up the steps. The following code is functionally equivalent to your one-liner:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my @a = 1 .. 5;
# @mapped contains the result of applying the block to each element of @a
my @mapped = map { $_ += 10 } @a;
say for @mapped;
```

Note that it is unnecessary (and perhaps undesirable) to use `$_ += 10` in your script, as this is modifying the elements in the original array `@a`. Using `$_ + 10` instead means that the returned value is different but the original value remains unmodified.

You don't *need* to use `map` as well as `for`, it just splits the process into two steps. Your code could just as easily be:

```
my @a = 1 .. 5;
say $_ + 10 for @a;
```

or

```
my @a = 1 .. 5;
map { say $_ + 10 } @a;
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's check what it means using [B::Deparse](http://search.cpan.org/~rjbs/perl-5.20.0/lib/B/Deparse.pm)

```
$ perl -MO=Deparse -wE'@a=(1..5); say $_ for map { $_+=10 } @a'
BEGIN { $^W = 1; }
use feature 'current_sub', 'evalbytes', 'fc', 'say', 'state', 'switch', 'unicode_strings', 'unicode_eval';
@a = 1..5;
say $_ foreach (map {$_ += 10;} @a);
-e syntax OK
```

So basically, you

- Enabled the warnings using `-w`.
- Enabled new features using `-E`.
- Create an array `@a` with 5 elements.
- Finally, iterating through the array `@a` and using map to transform the array content while modifying the array as well.

So bottom line as others have mentioned, `for` is just needed to iterate over the list that is returned by `map`.